# Trying to lookup horizontal

Tags: excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIbeN.jpg

I am looking to try and get column H to have the the word the has the highest volume next to it.

I tried using max as you can see in the image, and then using vlookup but that won't work.

[image: Sample dta layout]

Comment: in what coloumn is the word you wish to return?

Comment: Your lookup is still vertical, just right-to-left.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair and offset the range in the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) by one column in the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
=INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(I2,C2:G2,0))
```

[image]